# Getopt::Long & subroutines in GetOptions

Tags: perl, arguments

is there a possiblity to pass arguments to subroutine called via getopt::long ?
e.g i have this code calling &Salt when a user specifies **script.pl -pandora argument** on the commandline

```
GetOptions (            "domain=s"    => \$domain,
                        "pandora=s"   => \&Salt,
                        "reverse=s"   => \$reverse,
                        "help"        => \&Usage)
       or die(&Usage);
```

how do i get the argument to be passed to Salt ?
tried a couple of things such as :

```
GetOptions (            "domain=s"    => \$domain,
                        "pandora=s"   => \&Salt($pandora),
                        "reverse=s"   => \$reverse,
                        "help"        => \&Usage)
       or die(&Usage);
```

or even

```
    GetOptions (            "domain=s"    => \$domain,
                            "pandora=s"   => \&Salt($_[1]),
                            "reverse=s"   => \$reverse,
                            "help"        => \&Usage)
       or die(&Usage);
```

but it won't work

i know i can make it working by doing => $pandora, then using a condition in the code that says if ($pandora) { &Salt($pandora) } but i'll find it nicer to put the sub directly in getOptions if possible

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"pandora=s" => sub { my ($optname, $optval) = @_; Salt($optval) },
```

It can handle hashes too.

See the [User-defined subroutines to handle options](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options) section in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. works like a charm (will mark it as resolved in a few minutes)

Comment: You forgot the `= @_` if I'm not mistaken ;)

Comment: I prefer `"pandora=s" => sub { my $value = $_[1]; Salt($value) },`, since the first argument isn't used anyways, or even `"pandora=s" => sub { Salt($_[1]) },`. With the sub being this short, directly using `$_[1]` actually makes what's happening less obfuscated - as long as you have drilled into your head the two arguments that sub{} calls in GetOptions get.

Comment: @Silvar there can be three arguments if you have a hash. This code is trying to be explanatory, not short. I would skip the redundant assignments too.  :)

Comment: @jhnc Huh, you learn (or get reminded of) something new every day. I'm not in the habit of using hashes in GetOptions, so had forgotten or had never bothered to learn their use. Maybe next time I'll keep this in mind if the use case could benefit from it. Thanks.

Comment: @ysth Read jhnc's comment 3 above this; we were discussing arguments to the sub{}s in GetOptions in general, and not the question or solution at hand.